# STANDARD SQL DATA TYPE COMPARISON

Tags: python, sql, string, integer, sqldatatypes

**Question regarding Standard SQL data type comparisons.**

Given the following

```
SELECT *
FROM album
WHERE LENGTH(title) < 4
```

Returns 4 rows whose title lengths are less than 4.

On the other hand...

```
SELECT *
FROM album
WHERE LENGTH(title) < '4'
```

Returns all the rows irrespective of the title length.
Now, when I check `LENGTH(title) < 4`, it returns `true`.

Why would an `integer` be less than a `string`... ALWAYS?

The Standard SQL tool being used is both the SQL that can be found in **w3school.com** and Google's **BigQuery**.  I also noticed that the same would be try for **Python**.

Comment: Standard SQL - as in ISO 8859, also ANSI SQL? Expect an error.

Comment: Compare numbers to numbers and strings to strings.

Comment: standard sql is a rule work, the implementation is defined by the developers, but usually there is a inline conversion, so i doubt that it will return all rows

Comment: Tested this in Access query. Length of 12 compares as text to string criteria **"4"** - one character at a time. So since 1 is less than 4, the result is True. Whereas length of 9 is False. I reiterate: compare numbers to numbers and strings to strings.

Comment: It returns everything... I have tested it... at least in BigQuery

Comment: Here is a suggestion... go to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all and type the following

select 8 < '4', 8 > '4'

You will get 1,0... it does not matter what number you put on the right... basically the string is always greater than the number...